# Prevent passing route prefix as the first parameter to child routes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I prevent the Route prefix from being passed to all the child routes controller functions as the first parameter? It is messing with the $id parameter of my child routes!

```
Route::prefix('{locale?}')->middleware(['locale.default', 'locale'])->group(function() {
      Route::get('/car/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'CarController@getCar',
            'as' => 'car',
            'middleware' => 'auth'
        ])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
});
```

In CarController's getCar() function, the id parameter is getting the locale (en, fr, it) instead of the id of the car being passed.

```
public function getCar($id)
{
   $car = Car::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

To fix this, I must do:

```
public function getCar($locale, $id)
{
   $car = Car::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Is there a way to simply prevent the passing of $locale to the child route's controller functions so that I don't have to add $locale as the first parameter to every function?

If I change the getCar() parameter from $id to $request of type Request, I can do this and it works. Is this a good solution?

```
public function getCar(Request $request)
{ 
   $car = Car::where('id', $request->id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

The Laravel 5.6 docs seems to say that this can be done:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

> Accessing The Request Via Route Closures
>
> You may also type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request class on a route
>   Closure. The service container will automatically inject the incoming
>   request into the Closure when it is executed:
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
>
> Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
>       //... });

Can anyone confirm this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using a middleware, you simply need to add this line to the handler:

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('prefix');
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be wiser to use service provider for setting up the locale.

This article should guide you through the architecture for the multi-language and Laravel.

https://learninglaravel.net/forum/laraveltutorials/how-to-use-multiple-languages-in-your-laravel-5-website

All the best.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is exactly what I did. As can be seen in my code, I have 2 custom Middleware for handling the locale and setting the default local.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    unset($parameters['prefix']);

    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```

This should be called in your controller.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ignoring-few-route-parameters